# Cookie are present in the response cookies but not in browser

Tags: angular, cookies, nestjs, httpcookie

[image] [image] [image]

As I mentioned in the question cookies are present in the response header but it's not shown in the browser Application -> cookies
Here I added `withCredential` but it's not working.

**my angular code**

```
getSecretCode(passCode: number) {
     const httpOptions = {
       headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Accept': 'text/html',
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
       }), xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: true,
       }, credentials: 'include', mode: 'same-origin',
     };
     return this.http.post(this.serverUrl + '/secret', passCode, httpOptions)
   }
```

nestJs code

```
@Post()
     checkUserType(@Body() secret: secretEntity, @Response() res, @Request() req) {
         res.header('Set-Cookie', ["setFromServer=1;Max-Age=3600;", "jscantsee=1; sameSite=none;Max-Age=3600; path=/; httponly; secure;"]);
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin)
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST, OPTIONS')
         res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept')
         res.send()
        // return this.SecretService.checkUserType(secret);
     };
```

I saw most of the solution of stack but didn't get the answer. what i'm missing plz help. Thank you

Comment: `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true}`: I think this should just be `withCredentials: true`

Comment: yeah it's working Thanks! @lbsn